# How can I print something else in a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I´m having trouble with this while loop, because when it´s a valid password it still prints 'Invalid Password' and I don´t know how to fix it.

```
import re

password=input('Ingrese su password')
x=True
while x:
    if len(password)<6 and len(password)>12:
        break
    elif not re.findall('[a-z]',password):
        break
    elif not re.findall('[0-9]', password):
        break
    elif not re.findall('[A-Z]', password):
        break
    elif not re.findall('[$#@]',password):
        break
    else:
        print('Valid password')
        break
print('Invalid Password')
```

Comment: It isn't much of a loop if you always `break` in the first iteration. Also, `len(password)<6 and len(password)>12` will never be true.

Comment: Perhaps you need a function validate_password(password) returns bool. You can even write some unit tests for it.

Comment: @interjay yes I get that, but I don´t know how to do it differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the logical error in the first `if` statement, you have your `Invalid Password` phrase printing out regardless of other conditions after your `while` loop exits.

A more sensible way to construct this would be to create a password valid function that you can check in an if statement.

```py
import re

def valid_password(password):
    """Return True if the password meets all criteria, False otherwise"""
    # Check each criteria, returning False if they are not met.
    if len(password)<6 or len(password)>12:
        return False
    elif not re.findall('[a-z]',password):
        return False
    elif not re.findall('[0-9]', password):
        return False
    elif not re.findall('[A-Z]', password):
        return False
    elif not re.findall('[$#@]',password):
        return False

    # If we made it this far it means our password is good
    return True

  
password = input('Ingrese su password')

while not valid_password(password):
    print('Invalid Password')
    password = input('Ingrese su password')
print('Valid Password')
```

Comment: The only thing is that this exercise required me to do it with a while loop, and I don´t know how to connect the function with the while loop

Comment: What I imagine is the exercise wants you to be able to enter and re-enter a password until it is valid. I will update my answer to reflect that idea.

Answer (score 3):

Your condition to set the password valid is incorrect.
Change your AND by an OR

Comment: hmm I changed it but it still prints both 'Valid Password' and 'Invalid password'

Answer (score 3):

I think your error comes from the first if statement.

```
if len(password)<6 and len(password)>12:
```

should be:

```
if len(password)<6 or len(password)>12:
```

Otherwise you will allways get a invalid password message.
Greetings Leuko

Comment: I just changed it but it´s still  prints both 'Valid Password' and 'Invalid password' when I write a correct password

Comment: See my latest answer. Your "Invalid Password" phrase will print out regardless of the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be a simple password validation function:

```
def validate_password(passwd): 
      
    SpecialSym =['$', '@', '#', '%'] 
    val = True
      
    if len(passwd) < 6: 
        print('length should be at least 6 characters') 
        val = False
          
    if len(passwd) > 12: 
        print('length should not be greater than 12 characters') 
        val = False
          
    if not any(char.isdigit() for char in passwd): 
        print('Password should have at least one numeral') 
        val = False
          
    if not any(char.isupper() for char in passwd): 
        print('Password should have at least one uppercase letter') 
        val = False
          
    if not any(char.islower() for char in passwd): 
        print('Password should have at least one lowercase letter') 
        val = False
          
    if not any(char in SpecialSym for char in passwd): 
        print('Password should have at least one symbol') 
        val = False
    if val: 
        return val 
  
 
def main(): 
    passwd = 'Mypassword123@'
      
    if (validate_password(passwd)): 
        print("Password is valid") 
    else: 
        print("Invalid Password !!") 
          
        
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```